# Show $2^m\le (em)^n \Rightarrow m\leq 2n*\log_2(en)$

Tags: calculus, inequality

This is a small bonus question in a HW assignment for a machine-learning related course. We need to prove the following for $m,n\geq1$:
$$2^m\le (em)^n \Rightarrow m\leq 2n*\log_2(en)$$

A book we use in the course (Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Algorithms) mentions that this follows from another lemma:

Let $a\geq 1,b>0$. Then: $$x\geq 4a*\log_2⁡(2a)+2b\Rightarrow x\geq a*\log_2⁡(x)+b$$

However, I was unable to use it since I only get:
$$2^m\le (em)^n \Rightarrow m\leq n*\log_2(em)\Rightarrow m\leq n*\log_2(m)+n*\log_2(e)\Rightarrow$$
$$m\leq 4n*\log_2(2n)+2n*\log_2(e)$$

Any hints or directions will be greatly appreciated (we needn't necessarily use the aforementioned lemma, the book might be mistaken here).

Comment: Is $e$ the usual $\log_e=\ln$?

Comment: @Bo5man Yes, $e$ is the known constant.

Comment: @YadatiKiran Where is the inconsistency? I can fix my question if needed.

Comment: @DeanGurvitz: My bad. Didin't read the question properly.

Comment: Also in your last line the first $\log$ should be $\log_2$

Comment: Hint: Try to use the lemma you have written with $m>2n\log_2(en)\implies 2^m>(em)^n$.